# Which are the equivalent methods of py2neo-v2 merge_one, create_unique, find_one for py2neo v3?

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, py2neo

I recently switched my py2neo library from [version V2](https://py2neo.org/2.0/) to [version V3](https://py2neo.org/v3/index.html) and I don't know the new commands to perform certain opertions.

In particular I am stuck with:

### graph.merge_one

> Match or create a node by label and optional property and return a
> single matching node. This method is intended to be used with a unique
> constraint and does not fail if more than one matching node is found. ([read the docs](https://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html?highlight=merge_one#py2neo.Graph.merge_one))

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Node, Graph
nicole = Node("Person", name="Nicole", age=24) 

# adds the nicole element to the graph if it does not already exist a node labelled as "Person" having attribute "name" equal to "Nicole".
graph.merge_one("Person", "name", "Nicole")     #<-- What's the equivalent py2neo V3 command?
```

### graph.create_unique

> Create one or more unique paths or relationships in a single
> transaction. This is similar to create() but uses a Cypher CREATE
> UNIQUE clause to ensure that only relationships that do not already
> exist are created. ([read the docs](https://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html?highlight=create_unique#py2neo.Graph.create_unique))

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph

kenny = Node("Person", name="Kenny")
graph.create(kenny)

kingfish = Node("Bar", name="Kingfish")
graph.create(kingfish)

rel = Relationship(kenny, "LIKES", kingfish)

# creates the relationship (kenny)-[:LIKES]->(kingfish), but only if it does not exist yet.
graph.create_unique(rel)     #<-- What's the equivalent py2neo V3 command?
```

### graph.find_one

> Find a single node by label and optional property. This method is
> intended to be used with a unique constraint and does not fail if more
> than one matching node is found. ([read the docs](https://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html?highlight=find_one#py2neo.Graph.find_one))

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Graph

# Find one node (and take only one if there are many) matching these conditions: its type is "Person" and it has an attribute "name" equal to "Kenny", and then save it inside "kenny" variable.
kenny = graph.find_one("Person", "name", "Kenny")      #<-- What's the equivalent py2neo V3 command?
```

I found out that these methods are no longer available in py2neo V3, 
so what's the equivalent of these methods for py2neo V3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the equivalent methods for py2neo V3 (and also for [py2neo V.2020.1](https://py2neo.org/2020.1/index.html))

- `merge_one` -> `merge`
- `create_unique` -> in you example it is simply `merge`, because this
  is sufficient to ensure that

  > only relationships that do not already exist are created.
- `find_one` ->

  this is more complex and has to be splitted into more operations, 
  you can do it with `NodeMatcher` function and `match` method. 
  I'll show it directly in the example below.

Here are your examples changed to py2neo V3 commands:

### graph.merge_one

> Match or create a node by label and optional property and return a
> single matching node. This method is intended to be used with a unique
> constraint and does not fail if more than one matching node is found. ([read the docs][3])

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Node, Graph
nicole = Node("Person", name="Nicole", age=24) 

# adds the nicole element to the graph if it does not already exist a node labelled as "Person" having attribute "name" and "Person" and having their values equal to those of "nicole" element.
graph.merge(nicole, "Person", "name")
```

### graph.create_unique

> Create one or more unique paths or relationships in a single
> transaction. This is similar to create() but uses a Cypher CREATE
> UNIQUE clause to ensure that only relationships that do not already
> exist are created. ([read the docs][4])

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph

kenny = Node("Person", name="Kenny")
graph.create(kenny)

kingfish = Node("Bar", name="Kingfish")
graph.create(kingfish)

rel = Relationship(kenny, "LIKES", kingfish)

# creates the relationship (kenny)-[:LIKES]->(kingfish), but only if it does not exist yet.
graph.merge(rel)
```

### graph.find_one

> Find a single node by label and optional property. This method is
> intended to be used with a unique constraint and does not fail if more
> than one matching node is found. ([read the docs][5])

e.g.

```
from py2neo import Graph

# Find one node (and take only one if there are many) matching these conditions: its type is "Person" and it has an attribute "name" equal to "Kenny", and then save it inside "kenny" variable.
from py2neo import NodeMatcher
matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)
kenny = matcher.match('Person', name='Kenny').first()
```